# B&W film showing a man in atmospheric diving suit holding on to a scuba diver

Tags: story-identification, movie

B&W film showing a man in atmospheric diving suit holding on to a scuba diver.

[image: Still from the film]

Comment: Actually rather similar to a scene from James Bond film *For Your Eyes Only" -- only they had a newer-looking J.I.M. suit and were free of the lifting harness.

Comment: If you have more info about that movie, please [edit] it in. Just with that picture, it's not obvious the movie is science fiction or Fantasy.

Comment: Since this picture-ID question is confirmed to be about a science fiction film, it should be reopened

Answer (score 7):

This image is from *[Around The World Under The Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Around_the_World_Under_the_Sea)* (1966) or rather, it's a set photograph from the [Michael Ochs Archive](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/photos/michael-ochs-marshall-thompson?family=editorial&phrase=michael%20ochs%20Marshall%20Thompson&recency=anydate&sort=mostpopular&page=1&suppressfamilycorrection=true).

Various other photos of similar scenes were taken, presumably as 'continuity' shots.

> [image]
>
> Marshall Thompson looks like a giant monster on the ocean floor in a scene from the film 'Around The World Under The Sea', 1966. (Photo by Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer/Getty Images)

Comment: And that's cutting edge tech for 1966 -- almost SF in and of itself.